# 'neostore' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from

Tags: neo4j

I have follow error after restart neo4j-service:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'neostore' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NeoStore v0.A.0' but file is version 'NeoStore v0.A.1'.
```

I use version 2.0.2, but database last updated on version 2.0.0.

Can anyone help me?

TIA.

P.S. My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure to have a clean shutdown before upgrading to 2.0.2?

Comment: This database from other server. I checking it now.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster thanks, all work.